# What is wrong with this code that calculates areas, please? (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Hello, 
I am new to python. And I do not know why this code does not work:**

```
def area_finder_rectangle (height,width):
    area = height*width
    print("The area of your polygon is %.2f" % area)


def area_finder_triangle (height,width):
    area = (height*width)*0.5
    print("The area of your polygon is %.2f" % area)


while True:

    print ("Choose the polygon that you want to calculate the area from.")
    print ("Polygons supported: rectangle, triangle")
    value = str(input("Your polygon is a: "))
    print ("Be sure to include decimals even if you are going to input an integer")

    if value == "rectangle" or "Rectangle":

        heightt = float(input("Enter height: "))
        widthh = float(input("Enter width: "))
        area_finder_rectangle (height = heightt,width = widthh)

    elif value == "triangle" or "Triangle":
        heightt = float(input("Enter height: "))
        widthh = float(input("Enter width: "))
        area_finder_triangle (height = heightt,width = widthh)

    print ("")
```

**When you choose rectangle is just fine, but when you choose triangle, this happens:**

```
    >>>
    Choose the polygon that you want to calculate the area from.
    Polygons supported: rectangle, triangle
    Your polygon is a: triangle
    Be sure to include decimals even if you are going to input an integer
    Enter height: 10
    Enter width: 10
    The area of your polygon is 100.00
```

Comment: fix the indentation !!!

Comment: Indentation matters in Python. Badly indented code is nonsense.

Comment: it is well indented, i just idented it wrong when uploading it

Comment: Then [fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/45004469/edit). What's the use of posting code full of different errors from the ones you're asking about?

Comment: @khelwood Relax. It was fixed one minute after you commented first time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if value == "rectangle" or "Rectangle":
```

is not what you think it is. It will compare `value` with the complete result of the expression `"rectangle" or "Rectangle"` which will always evaluate to `True`. It should be like this:

```
if value == "rectangle" or value == "Rectangle":
```

But a better option is

```
if value.lower() == "rectangle":
```

Or even better, convert to lowercase directly at the input.

```
value = str(input("Your polygon is a: ")).lower()
```

Sidenote:

If you want to compare a value with several values, you can do like this:

```
if value in ["rectangle", "Rectangle", "RECTANGLE"]:
```

But in this case that's not an optimal option. Just convert to lowercase before comparing.

Here is complete code:

```
def area_finder_rectangle (height,width):
    area = height*width
    print("The area of your polygon is %.2f" % area)


def area_finder_triangle (height,width):
    area = (height*width)*0.5
    print("The area of your polygon is %.2f" % area)


while True:

    print ("Choose the polygon that you want to calculate the area from.")
    print ("Polygons supported: rectangle, triangle")
    value = str(input("Your polygon is a: ")).lower()
    print ("Be sure to include decimals even if you are going to input an integer")

    if value == "rectangle":

        heightt = float(input("Enter height: "))
        widthh = float(input("Enter width: "))
        area_finder_rectangle (height = heightt,width = widthh)

    elif value == "triangle":
        heightt = float(input("Enter height: "))
        widthh = float(input("Enter width: "))
        area_finder_triangle (height = heightt,width = widthh)

    print ("")
```

And a testrun:

```
[klutt@klutt-sandbox tmp]# python3 polygon.py
Choose the polygon that you want to calculate the area from.
Polygons supported: rectangle, triangle
Your polygon is a: rectangle
Be sure to include decimals even if you are going to input an integer
Enter height: 10.0
Enter width: 10.0
The area of your polygon is 100.00

Choose the polygon that you want to calculate the area from.
Polygons supported: rectangle, triangle
Your polygon is a: triangle
Be sure to include decimals even if you are going to input an integer
Enter height: 10.0
Enter width: 10.0
The area of your polygon is 50.00
```

One thing you should consider, which in this case would have made it easier for you to discover the problem, is to always add an `else` in case of non-valid input.

```
    if value == "rectangle":
        <do something>    
    elif value == "triangle":
        <do something>
    else:
        print("Unknown polygon")
```

Comment: Klutt, sorry for being such a noob in this thing... But I did what you said and it still did not worked. Sorry for being such an annoyance

Comment: The solution is correct. Try to print `value` before the `if` statement and check the content.

Comment: @klutt: There's no reason to call `str` on the return value of [`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input).

Comment: @Matthias True. Result of copy paste. But on the other hand I think poster is confused enough, and since it doesn't do any harm I'll leave it as it is.

Comment: @E.Leiva Please tell me HOW it does not work. It works for me.

Comment: I have the feeling that the OP won't answer again. He even accepted an answer with a total of 3 downvotes (at the moment).

Answer (score 3):

Your branch `if value == "rectangle" or "Rectangle:"` will always be taken and you will always calculate a rectangle.  Why it does this makes more sense if you put in parentheses.

```
    if (value == "rectangle") or ("Rectangle"):
```

If `value` is 'triangle' the first part evaluates to False but the second part of the or-condition evaluates to `True` since in Python a non-empty string in a boolean context is considered True.

To get the effect you want you need to say

```
    if (value == "rectangle") or (value == "Rectangle"):
```

Comment: Can you explain this more please, I'm new to this language and programming in general, and I'm not so technical in it.

Comment: In Python, and most other programming languages, the "or" in a test breaks the test into two parts.  The part before the "or" is tested and if it is True the value for the entire test if True.  If the part before the "or" is False then the second part of the test is run and the value of the whole test is whether the second part is True or False.  In your case the second part is a non-empty string which Python considers to be True.  Thus the if-test for a rectangle will always succeed.